# Wordpress using Much memory

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have wordpress website which i am running since last 3 years on a shared hosting plus plan which allots 512MB Ram for my account, and this site has 300000 Unique visitors per month. . .  and this site has a database file of 198 mb which has 602 posts, 100+ pages, 1000+ bbpress topics, 10000+ users registered, i do not know what happened suddenly, since last 4 days my site completely slowed down and some times completely down even there is no no traffic or only 10 unique visitors viewing the site, i am unable to perform any operations in database, regualrly i am getting Error establishing database connection error regularly. . .

I tried installing new wordpress site and connected to this database with out adding any plugins but no change, then i have took a VPS With 2 GB ram, 3 core processor, 1.5 TB bandwidth, and i tried installing new wordpress and connected to previous database (only included posts, post_meta, users, users_meta, comments, comments_meta) tables, removed all the plugins and themes and used default twenty twelve theme, as soon as i login to dashboard after connecting to this database, my memory usage within a span of 5 seconds reaching 100% from 11% and my vps server is shutting down. . .

I do not understand whats wrong with .. . . Please help me by suggesting your views

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are some plugins which helps you to find if any perfomrance lag by already installed plugins
try

[P3(Plugin Performance Profiler)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/)

Also, i suggest conduct a data scanning for any kind of  malicious scripts since the issue appears without your existing plugin and themes.
Also give a try by migrating your existing posts and user using some migration plugins available with WordPress

[WordPress Duplicator](http://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/)

And finally make sure you increased memory limit in your php.ini file and server configuration file